# Can I setState in the static method with react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a static method in my component as follows:

```
static updatestate(totalCount,totalCost){
   this.setState({totalCount,totalCost});
}
```

I only have to make the static method to pass data to the component.but as you know we can't use `this` in the static methods. Is there any way to pass data to a non-static method, without creating a new instance and without creating props. as following:

```
import MyComponentName from './MyComponentName.js';
MyComponentName.MyMethod(params)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you state, you can't use `this` in static methods.

If you are trying to invoke a method on a specific component instance, use a `ref` to that instance. Suppose you wanted to invoke `updateState` on this component:

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {totalCount: 0, totalCost: 0};

  updateState = (totalCount, totalCost) => {
    this.setState({totalCount, totalCost});
  }

  render() {
    const {totalCount, totalCost} = this.state;
    return <Text>totalCount: {totalCount} totalCost: {totalCost}</Text>;
  }
}
```

You would get a `ref` to an instance, and can then call `updateState`:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ChildComponent ref={child => {
          this.child = child; // gets a ref to the child component 
        }} />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
          const {totalCount, totalCost} = this.child.state;
          this.child.updateState(totalCount + 1, totalCost + 10); // call method on child component
        }}><Text>press</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

(If instead, you want to `setState` on *all* instances of a component, you might be better offer using a `React.createContext` `Provider` that the ChildComponent's could be a `Consumer` of).

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! but when I run this code I receive this error: Undefined is not an object(evaluating this.child.updatestate)

Comment: Works for me? I have the exact code above with following changes:

1. I have the components in two files, `ParentComponent.js` & `ChildComponent.js`
2. I have changed `class` to `export default class`
3. ChildComponent has `import React from 'react';` and `import {Text} from 'react-native';`
4. ParentComponent has `import React from 'react';`, `import {Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';` and `import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';`
5. I have included `<ParentComponent />` in my App.

If you still have problems, post your app to a Github repo and I'll take a look